# Not able to access kafka(confluent) installed on Azure VM using public IP

Tags: apache-kafka

I have installed confluent-oss-5.0.0 on Azure VM and exposed all necessary ports to access using public IP Address.

I tried to change the **etc/kafka/server.properties** below things to achieve but no luck

```
Approach - 1

listeners=PLAINTEXT://:9092
advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://<publicIP>:9092

--------------------------------------            
Approach - 2

advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://<publicIP>:9092

--------------------------------------            
Approach - 3

listeners=PLAINTEXT://<publicIP>:9092
```

I experienced below error

```
pj@pj-HP-EliteBook-840-G1:~/confluent-kafka/confluent-oss-5.0.0/bin$ kafka-console-producer --broker-list <publicIp>:9092 --topic pj_test123>dfsds
[2019-03-25 19:13:38,784] WARN [Producer clientId=console-producer] Connection to node -1 could not be established. Broker may not be available. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)


pj@pj-HP-EliteBook-840-G1:~/confluent-kafka/confluent-oss-5.0.0/bin$ kafka-console-producer --broker-list <publicIp>:9092 --topic pj_test123
>message1
>message2
>[2019-03-25 19:20:13,216] ERROR Error when sending message to topic pj_test123 with key: null, value: 3 bytes with error: (org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.ErrorLoggingCallback)
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Expiring 2 record(s) for pj_test123-0: 1503 ms has passed since batch creation plus linger time
[2019-03-25 19:20:13,218] ERROR Error when sending message to topic pj_test123 with key: null, value: 3 bytes with error: (org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.ErrorLoggingCallback)




pj@pj-HP-EliteBook-840-G1:~/confluent-kafka/confluent-oss-5.0.0/bin$ kafka-console-consumer --bootstrap-server <publicIp>:9092 --topic pj_test123 --from-beginning
[2019-03-25 19:29:27,742] WARN [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=console-consumer-42352] Error while fetching metadata with correlation id 2 : {pj_test123=LEADER_NOT_AVAILABLE} (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)

pj@pj-HP-EliteBook-840-G1:~/confluent-kafka/confluent-oss-5.0.0/bin$ kafka-console-consumer --bootstrap-server <publicIp>:9092 --topic pj_test123 --from-beginning
[2019-03-25 19:27:06,589] WARN [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=console-consumer-33252] Connection to node 0 could not be established. Broker may not be available. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
```

All other service like zookeeper, kafka-connect and restAPI are working fine using the <PublicIP>:<port>

```
kafka-topics --zookeeper 13.71.115.20:2181 --list  --- This is working
```

Ref: 
[Not able to access messages from confluent kafka on EC2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52753098/not-able-to-access-messages-from-confluent-kafka-on-ec2)

https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#brokerconfigs

[Why I cannot connect to Kafka from outside?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27191347/why-i-cannot-connect-to-kafka-from-outside)

***Solutions***

Thanks, @Robin Moffatt, It works for me. I do below changes along with allowing all Kafka related ports on Azure networking

```
kafka@kafka:~/confluent-oss-5.0.0$ sudo vi etc/kafka/server.properties 

listeners=INTERNAL://0.0.0.0:9092,EXTERNAL://0.0.0.0:19092
listener.security.protocol.map=INTERNAL:PLAINTEXT,EXTERNAL:PLAINTEXT
advertised.listeners=INTERNAL://<privateIp>:9092,EXTERNAL://<publicIp>:19092
inter.broker.listener.name=INTERNAL
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to configure both internal and external listeners for your broker. This article details how: https://rmoff.net/2018/08/02/kafka-listeners-explained/.

Comment: It works for me

```
kafka@kafka:~/confluent-oss-5.0.0$ sudo vi etc/kafka/server.properties 

listeners=INTERNAL://0.0.0.0:9092,EXTERNAL://0.0.0.0:19092
listener.security.protocol.map=INTERNAL:PLAINTEXT,EXTERNAL:PLAINTEXT
advertised.listeners=INTERNAL://<privateIp>:9092,EXTERNAL://<publicIp>:19092
inter.broker.listener.name=INTERNAL
```

Comment: First I kept INTERNAL port as 19092 and changed few other places(etc/kafka/connect-distributed.properties, connect-standalone.properties, kafka-rest.properties, ksql-server.properties ...) with port 19092. But It did not work and new other issues come to the picture (like kafka-connect, shcema-registry not started). Also debezium mysql connector did not work. Any clue on this?

Answer (score 0):

You will also have to give public access to port 9092 (your broker). TO do that,

1. Go to your Virtual machine in Azure portal
2. Select Networking under settings in the left menu
3. Add inbound port rule
4. Add port 9092 to be accessbile from anywhere